# How to properly annotate methods with generic collections using Eclipse external Annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, null-check, external-annotations

I'm trying to annotate the method `java.util.List.toArray` using Eclipse's external annotations, but I'm not sure how to annotate the return type. If my List has the following signature:

```
@NonNull List<@NonNull Element>
```

List.toArray should return:

```
@NonNull Element @NonNull[]
```

If, however, the list can contain nullable elements:

```
@NonNull List<@Nullable Element>
```

List.toArray should return an array with nullable elements, too:

```
@NonNull Element @Nullable[]
```

I'm using Eclipse Neon, is this even possible? The [Eclipse Neon New and Noteworthy page](https://www.eclipse.org/neon/noteworthy/#_null_analysis) seems to provide an example for List.get() and suggests that I should ommit the nullity for the value, but that doesn't seem to work for arrays? Here is the external annotation definition I'm using:

```
class java/util/List
toArray
 <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>([TT;)[TT;
 <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>([T1T;)[T1T;
```

But this doesn't work:

```
    @NonNull
    List<@NonNull String> collect = // works
    @NonNull
    String @NonNull [] array = collect.toArray(new String[0]);
```

`collect.toArray` is marked as error:

> Null type safety (type annotations): The expression of type 'String[]' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@NonNull String []'

How can I fix this? Does this even work with Eclipse Neon, yet?

Comment: `toArray` return the same type you pass as parameter, and `new String[0]` has no `@NonNull` annotation. But note that there is no connection between the array type and the `Collection`’s element type, e.g. you could even write `String[] array = collect.toArray(new String[0]);` when `collect` has the type `List<Integer>`. It would even work if the `List` is empty. Regarding the nullness, it would require special treatment by the checker, but note that the contract is special: if the array is bigger than the collection’s size, the array element following the last element will be `null`ed out.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this advice](https://rtist.hcldoc.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_external_null_annotations.htm&cp=1_3_9_2_4&anchor=annotation_kind) and followed it in Eclipse 2020-03: I **placed the cursor between the "T" and the "[]" of the return type**, opened the context menu, and selected "Annotate as Not Null". This had the desired effect, as if the method was declared

```
@NonNull <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

The generated List.eea file looks like this:

```
class java/util/List
toArray
 <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>([TT;)[TT;
 <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>([TT;)[1TT;
```